# how do you unlock a government owned apple MacBook 2013 I bought it at a school auction

Tags: macbook-pro

unlocking the bion system new firmware cracking the code terminal

Comment: What exactly is locked, what kind of error do you get?

Comment: @ – 
nohillside
♦
I am able to get in and everything I just can't factory reset it from disk utility recovery

Comment: What prevents you from doing a factory reset then?

Comment: @nohillside keeps asking for admin password

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

- Take it back to wherever you bought it and ask them to unlock it
- Take it to the next Apple Store together with a proof of purchase/ownership and have it unlocked